# (Help) Error loading BMP file

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I have some problems loading a BMP file at RAM memory.

Apparently, the image is loaded well but when it is shown by a OpenGL program is seen bad. The program doesn't throws any error (it is in C++)

The code:

```
TEXTURE::TEXTURE(const char *path) {
    unsigned char header[54];
    unsigned int dataPos;
    unsigned int width, height, size;
    unsigned char *data;
    FILE *filePointer = fopen(path, "rb");

    if(filePointer == NULL)
        printf_s("Error openning image file at '%s'!", path);

    if(!fread(header, 1, 54, filePointer))
        printf_s("Error, file at '%s' isn't a real BMP file.", path);

    if(header[0] != 'B' || header[1] != 'M')
        printf_s("Error, file at '%s' isn't a real BMP file.", path);

    dataPos = *(int *)&header[0x0A];
    size    = *(int *)&header[0x22];
    width   = *(int *)&header[0x12];
    height  = *(int *)&header[0x16];

    if(!size)
        size = width * height * 3;

    if(!dataPos)
        dataPos = 54;

    data = new unsigned char[size];
    fread(data, 1, size, filePointer);

    fclose(filePointer);

    glGenTextures(1, &texID);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

The result (Info on the image isn't important):

(I can't post images...) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny2YD.jpg

The original image: http://k33.kn3.net/C/B/A/4/0/C/DB2.bmp

Vertex shader source:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoords;

out DATA {
    vec2 texCoords;
} vs_out;

void main() {
    gl_Position = position;

    vs_out.texCoords = texCoords;
}
```

Fragment shader source:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

in DATA {
    vec2 texCoords;
} fs_in;

uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main() {
    color = texture(sampler, fs_in.texCoords);
}
```

Comment: Do you know that the file content is RGB, not RGBA? Also, if it is indeed RGB, you will need a `glPIxelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` call if the width is not a multiple of 4.

Comment: The image size is 512x512 pixels (is is perfect). Im sure i saved it as 24 bits BMP image (RGB).

Comment: And magic art makes sense on my code! Now, without doing anything, it does the correct thing... thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) library 
it's easy to load any type of image as a texture automatically ,see test_SOIL.cpp example inside ,it will be helpful